# Keras backend is not changed in my conda environment

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, backend, keras, conda

Recently I am exploring deep learning with Keras on my ubuntu14.04 system and encountered a weird issue with the backend of Keras. 
I always run my code in a conda virtual environment and I would like to use keras with tensorflow backend. Following the official document, I am sure that the keras.json has the backend set as 'tensorflow' as shown in the screenshot below:
[keras.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isrcb.png)

However, whenever I import keras in the conda virtual environment it always says that the keras backend is theano. I have no idea how this happens and how to fix it. Another weird issue is that, sometimes when I created a new conda environment, I got backend as tensorflow in the new environment. However, the next day when I import keras in the same environment the backend is set to theano. My keras.json file still set backend as tensorflow at the mean time.

Hope someone can help me with this issue. Thank you very much!
[keras backend in conda environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYYeR.png)

Comment: Have you tried to change `keras.json` in your `env` folder?

Comment: It seems that .keras does not exist in env folder in my conda virtual environment. @MarcinMożejko

Comment: I figured out a work around by looking at the __init__.py under keras folder. It seems that whenever the keras is initialized in a conda virtual environement. Th backend variable will be set as `_BACKEND=os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']`. And for some reason, the `os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']` variable is always set to 'theano'.
While it is not clear how the `os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']` is defined originally,  we can always reset this variable before we import keras.

Comment: in keras_activate.sh and activate.sh
Linux is fixed to theano, while mac is fixed to tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

I am running anaconda on mac. and I encounter a similar issue like yours. For my case, I cannot change the backend to Theano. Here is what I have done to resolve this issue.

In **init**.py change **_BACKEND = 'tensorflow'** to **_BACKEND = 'theano'**

In keras.json
remove 
**"backend": "tensorflow"**

and finally in anaconda

**from keras import backend as K**

**K.backend()**

'theano'

Hope this helps you